# How to use the print one condition instead of two with the same variable

Tags: java

I've got this exercise which talks adding scheduled and estimated times as parameters.

In the questions, 10:15 am is represented as 615 (=10*60+15).

And 8:15 pm as 1215 (= 20*60+15).

This gave me an idea to create variables out of these.

My problem is that I couldn't get the print output "The train is delayed by x minute" by itself. It always prints out with "Claim compensation"

I don't think I'm allowed to create additional methods other than the main method and printTrainDelay.

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    int hourOne = 10;
    int hourTwo = 20;
    int min = 60;
    int second = 15;

    int timeOne = hourOne * min + second;
    int timeTwo = hourTwo * min + second;
    printTrainDelay(timeOne,timeTwo);
}

public static int printTrainDelay (int scheduledTimes, int estimatedTimes) {
    if (estimatedTimes == scheduledTimes){
        System.out.println("The train is on time");
    }
    if (estimatedTimes < 1) {
        System.out.println("The train is delayed by 1 minute");
    }
    if (estimatedTimes > 1) {
        System.out.println("The train is delayed by x minute");
    }
    if estimatedTimes > 30){
        System.out.println("Claim compensation");
    }

    return estimatedTimes;
}
```

}

I expect the print output to show just one condition instead of two.

Comment: You need to also use `else`, not just pure `if`

Comment: Did you mean `"The train is delayed by x minutes"`? (notice the “s” at the end)

Comment: @Bohemian My question is to stop printing two outputs at the same time. These are `The train is delayed by x minutes` and `Claim compensation`, I just want one. This question has already been answered by the use of subtraction and else if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got multiple `if` conditions that are satisfied (*3rd* and *4th*), therefore, both `println` are displayed.

You'd need to use `if-else` blocks. If you use it only the block with first passing `if`  condition will be executed

```
 //you can extract time difference to a variable to avoid recalculating it
int timeDifference = scheduledTimes - estimatedTimes;only once

if (timeDifference == 0){
    System.out.println("The train is on time");
} else if (timeDifference < 1) {
    System.out.println("The train is delayed by 1 minute");
} else if (timeDifference > 1) {
    System.out.println("The train is delayed by x minute");
} else if (timeDifference > 30) {
    System.out.println("Claim compensation");
}
```

Comment: This does works very well. Thank you for this wonderful solution!